# Should Ureaplasma Urealyticum be treated if it doesn't cause any symptoms?

Tags: bacteria, urology, gynecology, sti

[Ureaplasma Urealyticum](https://www.thesticlinic.com/ureaplasma-urealyticum.aspx) is a bacterium that can be passed through sexual contact although it is not considered a classic STI or STD because of its low degree of pathogenicity [(ie, harm the infected person)](http://www.tulane.edu/~wiser/protozoology/notes/Path.html). The two species of Ureaplasma are Parvum and Urealyticum.

On one hand it may not lay dormant forever and once the immune resistance is weakened it may cause inflammation. On the other hand treatment (antibiotics) may actually cause more harm than Ureaplasma itself.

What is the modern approach to this?
Is there a consensus?
What are the criteria to decide whether the treatment is required?